# Unable to apply fill for path drawn rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to form a cell object using paths in HTML5 Canvas. But I am unable to apply fill for the path I made. Tried out several things but not able to solve it.

```
class Cell {
  constructor({ i, j }) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.visited = false;
    this.walls = [true, true, true, true]; // top right bottom left
    this.show = canvasContext => this._show(canvasContext);
  }

  _show(ctx) {
    const x = this.j * cellSize;
    const y = this.i * cellSize;
    if (!this.visited) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    }
    // ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    if (this.walls[0]) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + cellSize, y); // top
    }
    if (this.walls[3]) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y + cellSize); // left
    }
    if (this.walls[1]) {
      ctx.moveTo(x + cellSize, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + cellSize, y + cellSize); // right
    }
    if (this.walls[2]) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y + cellSize);
      ctx.lineTo(x + cellSize, y + cellSize); // bottom
    }
    ctx.fill();      
    ctx.stroke();
    // ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

See the Pen [Maze Generator](https://codepen.io/dhanushuUzumaki/pen/bLopVO/) by Dhanushu ([@dhanushuUzumaki](https://codepen.io/dhanushuUzumaki)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you aren't creating a closed shape, you are just creating a series of lines that don't form a shape.

This is a closed path. If you took a pencil and drew the points, you'd see that it would be closed.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "#F00"; // red
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0"; // green

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas />
```

This is an open path, who's stroke looks the same:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "#F00"; // red
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0"; // green

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 50);

ctx.moveTo(100, 50);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);

ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);

ctx.moveTo(50, 100);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);

ctx.closePath();

ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas />
```

By calling `moveTo()` you are essentially picking the pencil up, and breaking the shape. There is nothing to fill, because it's not one contiguous path. It's just 4 separate lines that are close to one another.

For your particular problem, I see two ways to solve this. The first would be to stop using `moveTo()` so often and just draw the lines. However, for your particular problem, that could be tricky.

Instead, what you might draw to do is draw individual rectangles to fill in each block of your grid. It seems like that logic might be easier to work out.

Comment: Hi, I can't use rectangle because I will throwing off one or more of the lines forming the rectangle in future. They are kind of like walls. And I tried using closePath() it didn't work.. so I think I removed it before posting.

Comment: It's not about using `closePath()`. It's the fact that you keep calling `moveTo()`. If you imagine drawing your instructions with a pencil, `moveTo()` tells you to pick up the pencil, thus breaking the shape. It has to be one continuous shape in order for fill to work. If you can't use rectangles, you will instead need to work out logic so you can draw all of your lines without using `moveTo()` more than the first time.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I did what you said and it worked but then I was having some other issues so what I did was create the walls with strokes and drew a rectangle with same coordinates and filled it. now I have what I wanted. You can check it out here.. https://codepen.io/dhanushuUzumaki/full/bLopVO/ its a maze generator.. Thanks a lot again